# How to set direction RTL with phpWord addHtml

Tags: php, phpword

I'm struggling with converting HTML to MS word. I used phpWord and everything is working fine, but I can not find how to set direction rtl. It ignores HTML style tag with direction.

My code that works:

```
$word = 'C:\wamp\www\myproject\vendor\autoload.php';

        require_once($word);
        if (isset($_POST['file_name'])) {

            $file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
            $file_content = $_POST['file_content'];

            $file_content = str_replace('<br>','<br/>', $file_content);


            $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
            $section = $phpWord->addSection();

            \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $file_content, false, false);

            $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');

            $objWriter->save('document.docx');
        }
```

The rtl  for text should be added like this:

```
        $fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
        $fontStyle->setRTL(true);
        $fontStyle->setLang('he-IL');
```

but I can not find how to set it for addHTML

Thanks

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
I edited addHTML function and after $element added array with styles

self::parseNode($node->item(0), $element, array('font' => array('size'=>24, 'rtl'=>true, 'lang'=>'he-IL')));

now I see when I print phpWord that rtl is set to 1, BUT

when document is created font size is 24 and text is not rtl

Comment: You might have to use the `rtl` option as part of the Font object. http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html?highlight=right%20to%20left

Comment: I wrote that... it is not problem if i use add text... the problem is when i use add html